# SQL Server : get the row Identity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this as the first part of a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @_id as int

if exists(select 1 from JTrack_Visitors WHERE cookie = @cookie)
begin
    UPDATE JTrack_Visitors 
    SET LastSeen = @_now 
    WHERE cookie = @cookie
end
else
begin
    INSERT INTO JTrack_Visitors(Cookie, CreatedOn, LastSeen)
    VALUES (@cookie, @_now, @_now)
end
```

How can I set `@_id` to be the identity of the row either being inserted or updated? I need that value to use later in the stored procedure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of OUTPUT clause in your both statements, in either case populate a table variable and later retrieve value from that table variable.

```
DECLARE @_id as int;
DECLARE @ID_Table TABLE(ID INT);

IF EXISTS (select 1 from JTrack_Visitors WHERE cookie = @cookie)
  BEGIN
       UPDATE JTrack_Visitors 
         SET LastSeen = @_now 
       OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @ID_Table(ID)
       WHERE cookie = @cookie
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO JTrack_Visitors(Cookie,CreatedOn,LastSeen)
    OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @ID_Table(ID)
    VALUES (@cookie,@_now,@_now)
  END

SELECT @_id = ID FROM @ID_Table;
```

Comment: OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @ID_Table(ID) gives me Invalid column name 'ID'.

Comment: use `inserted.[Your_Identity_Column_name]` instead of just `ID`, I used this only for demo purpose

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the SQL Server version you're using you could use the [MERGE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) including the OUTPUT clause to get the values you're looking for.
This would also eliminate the need to check for existence and either update or insert.

Comment: Needs to be support on 2005. Is there any way to do it without using MERGE?

Comment: You could use SELECT @_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() right after the UPDATE and after the INSERT statement.